# Evento de JButton de un JPanel externo sobre JTable de un JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jtable, jpanel

Muy buenas tardes,

Estoy creando un pequeño programa para la gestión de comandas en un restaurante.

Para ello tengo un *JFrame* en el cual tengo varios botones para las categorías de los distintos productos.

Cuando pulso sobre el botón de "Agua" el producto se inserta en la base de datos y se añade una fila con la info del producto a un *JTable*.

Pero cuando una categoría tiene varios productos como por ejemplo "Postres" al pulsar sobre dicho botón me aparece en este *JFrame* un *JPanel* con distintos botones correspondientes a los distintos postres que tiene el restaurante.

Código del evento del botón postres:

```
btnNewButton_7_7_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        
        Panel_Postres panel_postres=new Panel_Postres(s, num_mesa);
        
        panel_3.removeAll();
        panel_3.add(panel_postres);
        panel_3.repaint();
        panel_3.revalidate();
    }
});
```

Y al pulsar sobre alguno de los postres que muestra el *JPanel* como por ejemplo "Tarta de queso" tendría que hacer el mismo procedimiento que con el botón "Agua", es decir: Inserta el producto en la base de datos y añadir una fila con la info del producto al *JTable* del *JFrame*. Pero la fila insertada se añade a la base de datos pero no al *JTable*.

Código del evento del botón Tarta de queso:

```
btnNewButton_7_16.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        
        String sala=s;
        int num=num_mesa;
        String articulo="Tarta de queso";
        int unidades=1;
        double precio= 5.00;
        double total_linea=5.00;
        
        Tpv tpv=new Tpv(num, sala);
        
        int numCols = tpv.table.getModel().getColumnCount();

        Object [] fila = new Object[numCols]; 
                
         fila[0] = articulo;
         fila[1] = unidades;
         fila[2] = precio;
         fila[3] = total_linea;
         
         ((DefaultTableModel)tpv.table.getModel()).addRow(fila);
         
         int unid=cp.obtenerUnidades(sala, num, articulo);
         double total=cp.obtenerTotalLinea(sala, num, articulo);
         
         if(unid>0) {
             cp.modificarArt(sala, num, articulo, unid+1, precio, total);
         }else {
             cp.insertarComanda(sala, num, articulo, unidades, precio, total_linea);
         }
    }
});
```

¿Qué es lo que puede suceder?

Llevo ya varios días y no encuentro ninguna solución...

Gracias de antemano!
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué es "tpv"? Si es la tabla donde quieres que aparezcan los datos, ¿por qué creas una nueva instancia?

Comment: Tpv es el JFrame donde se encuentra el JTable

Comment: No. Es una nueva instancia, un objeto distinto. No estás metiendo los datos en el Tpv que se muestra, los estas metiendo en otro objeto.

Comment: Entonces ¿Como puedo acceder a esa tabla?

Comment: Podría crear un método en la clase Tpv que se encargara de insertar los datos en la JTable y llamar a ese método desde el JPanel?